Point of application of a magnetic force
I have recently come across a problem that involves calculating a magnetic force and finding the torque it generates on a rigid conductive wire. The inconvenience is that I need a point of application to find the torque and just as it is presented there is not enough information. My professor assumed that it acts at the midpoint of segment $AC$ below.

Current $I$ is going through the circuit and an external magnetic field perpendicular to plane $ACB$ produces a magnetic force on segment $AC$. How can I prove that the magnetic force will act at the midpoint? The external magnetic field is assumed to be uniform.

An infinitesimal magnetic force acts on every infinitesimal segment of AC. Do you know how to integrate the torque that these forces cause?

Yes. I didn't think such a simple approach would work. Integrating the torque gives you exactly the torque as if it acted at the midpoint.

Technically, there is no point of application of a force on a rigid body. You can only define a line of force (whose direction is along the force). You can apply the same force anywhere on the line with the same mechanical effect.

I see. I recall from a dynamics book I used that they call this the principle of transmissibility. Basically then what we have is that the net magnetic force acts on a line through the midpoint perpendicular to $AC$. How is it possible to relate those two notions? Dynamics of rigid bodies and magnetic fields seem pretty far apart from each other. Are there any resources where one can read more on the topic?
